# MySQL select number of element for field

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I'm trying to get some data from MySQL which is structured like this

```
id  name        url
1   foo         SOMEURL
2   foo         SOMEURL
3   foo         SOMEURL
4   foo         SOMEURL
5   bar         SOMEURL
6   bar         SOMEURL
7   bar         SOMEURL
8   bar         SOMEURL
9   oop         SOMEURL
10  oop         SOMEURL
11  dpk         SOMEURL
12  more        SOMEURL
```

I want to get the number of item for `name` starting with 0, for example

```
id  name        url         number
1   foo         SOMEURL     0
2   foo         SOMEURL     1
3   foo         SOMEURL     2
4   foo         SOMEURL     3
5   bar         SOMEURL     0
6   bar         SOMEURL     1
7   bar         SOMEURL     2
8   bar         SOMEURL     3
9   oop         SOMEURL     0
10  oop         SOMEURL     1
11  dpk         SOMEURL     0
12  more        SOMEURL     0
```

But I don't know how to, the far I went was `GROUP_CONCAT` the `url` field and grouping by `name` so I get the number of total items, but not what I wanted (asked here)

To clarify, there are only three fields on my table, which are `id` `name` and `url`. The `number` column is generated through the query I'm asking for. I want that number start by 0 but it cant start in any number, it just have to reset on each different name, so I get like a one by one row count for each name... I think that the example is very clear.

Comment: you can use mysql built in function for count the number of field..like clause also used for pattern matching.. **'select count(name) from table_Name where number like %0%;'**

Comment: number doesn't exists, number is created through the query I'm asking. There are only 3 fields in my table, `id`, `name` and `url` I want to get the row number for each name starting with 0 (or 1 I don't care)

Comment: I personally recommend to avoid doing that in SQL query. If these numbers are meaningful part of your data, store them in table itself. If you need numbers for visual representation, do it in programming language. Pure SQL is declarative. You say what you need and DBMS gives it to you. You shouldn't maintain program state in query. That's why it's hard to accomplish such a simple task. DB (ideally) contains pure data and gives you pure data whereas you're trying to define its look with help of SQL. I had a bitter experience with moving logic into DB. Don't to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to do it with mysql, then you can use dynamic variable.

```
mysql> create table test (id int, name varchar(100));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.21 sec)

mysql> insert into test values (1,'foo'),(2,'foo'),(3,'foo'),(4,'bar'),(5,'oop'),(6,'bar'),(7,'oop');
Query OK, 7 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Records: 7  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

select id,
name,
number 
from ( 
   select *, 
   @rn := if(@prev = name, @rn+1,0) as number , 
   @prev:=name 
   from test,(select @rn:=0,@prev:='')r order by name 
)t ;
```

The output will be as

```
+------+------+--------+
| id   | name | number |
+------+------+--------+
|    4 | bar  |      0 |
|    6 | bar  |      1 |
|    1 | foo  |      0 |
|    2 | foo  |      1 |
|    3 | foo  |      2 |
|    5 | oop  |      0 |
|    7 | oop  |      1 |
+------+------+--------+
```

This will display the data sort by name.

Comment: Perfect, that was the solution I was looking for. I needed to add the `url` field because I need it, but everything worked

Answer (score 0):

With any programming language you can:
(Note the following is pseudo-code very much like PHP but without actually writing all the code for connecting to your database, etc)

```
$numbers = array();
$output = array();
select all rows of your table
foreach row {
    if ( array_key_exists($row['name'], $numbers ) {
        $numbers[$row['name]]++;
    } else {
        $numbers[$row['name']] = 0;
    }
    $output[] = array(
        "id" => $row['id'],
        "name" => $row['name'],
        "url" => $row['url'],
        "number" => $numbers[$row['name']]
    );
}
```

At this point you will have an array that will look like:

```
[
    {"id": 1 , "name": "foo", "url": "SOMEURL", "number": 0],
    {"id": 2 , "name": "foo", "url": "SOMEURL", "number": 1],
    etc...
]
```

Comment: Yes, that's a solution using a programming language, but I want it on the query itself, it's cleaner and I don't depend on loops.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from your_table group by url,name
```

Comment: Well, this isn't what I asked at all, your query only groups by url and name, doesn't show me the item number.